# Accessing multi lingual .properties files in Android API 33

Tags: android, mobile-development, resourcebundle, android-api-33

Attached screenshots shows my project folder structures,
[properties files stored like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SUUs.png)

And I am able to access those properties files by following code,
[able to access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBY18.png)

But after I changed my app to API 33 and generated signed APK in release mode, I am not able to access these files and its throwing following error,

java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name res/raw/lang, locale en_EN

APK generated in debug mode is working, I am seeing this error only in apk generated in release mode.

Need help.